# Absorbing Markov Chains: An efficient algorithmic approach

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, markov-chains

Following [this procedure](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m20x06/public_html/Lecture14.pdf) I have successfully written a program to calculate the probability of ending in a given absorbing state given the initial state.  The procedure is as follows:

1. Given the transition matrix (P), row and column swap until the identity matrix is in the bottom right corner.

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix} 
Q & R \\
0 & I 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

2. Calculate the matrix N, and multiply by R to give the final probability matrix (B).

$$N = (I-Q)^{-1}$$
$$B = N*R$$

Where the values in B represent the probability of moving from an initial non-absorbing state (rows) to a final absorbing state.

**My question is** if there is a more efficient method for solving this problem *if I know what my initial state is*.  It seems wasteful to calculate the entire B matrix, given that I will only ever use one row in it.

I am writing a program to do this, so the matrix inversion step is particularly inefficient.  Can I avoid this altogether?

Comment: You should read Section 1.3 of Norris' Markov Chains (available here: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/).